# How to send Stripe session checkout parameters in subscription mode

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am quite new to stripe integration, and due to the country I am from, I cannot access the checkout session page due to account activation requirements.
So, I am not able to see what all details are visible in the checkout page, and cannot debug it. (I am in test mode)

I am quite confused about how I can sent the price id of the product I select.
I have created two products in my dashboard, and I am displaying then on the frontend with a pay button that calls the `checkout-session` endpoint.

this is my checkoutSession view

```
class CreateCheckoutSession(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            

            try:

                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    print(request.user)
                    print(request.user.id)
                    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                        client_reference_id=request.user.id,
                        payment_method_types=['card'],
                        line_items=[
                            {
                                'price': "",  
                                'quantity': 1,
                            },
                        ],
                        mode='subscription',
                        success_url=os.environ['DOMAIN_URL']+'/dashboard',
                        cancel_url=os.environ['DOMAIN_URL'],
                    )
                    return Response({'sessionId': checkout_session.id})
                else:
                    return Response({'message': 'You need to register first.'}, status=403)

            except InvalidRequestError as e:
                error_message = str(e)
                return Response({'error': error_message}, status=400)

        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Method not allowed'}, status=405)
```

I think I should only send the price id or product id (which one am I supposed to send?) of the subscription I want to buy. I am not sure how can I do that. Could anyone please help me here?
My frontend is NEXTJS and backend is django with DRF

```
const handleSubscription = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await AxiosInstance.post("/checkout-session", {
        
      });
      
      const sessionId = response.data.sessionId;
      const stripe = await loadStripe(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
      );
      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: sessionId,
      });

      if (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
```

When calling the product api, it gives me two arrays, one for each product.
I need your help to understand, what are the parameters that I need to send of the product I subscribe to?
and how can I sent it?

I tried implementing the stripe code implementation using stripe elements, and now switching to stripe low code, as it best suits my current use case.
I cannot check if my payment is going through successfully, as I cannot make any payment from my country before account activation due to stripe policies.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot make any payment from my country before account activation due to stripe policies.

Why don't you use your test API keys? You can make test payments and Checkout sessions without an activated Stripe account.

As for the formatting of the `line_items` array, you have two choices:

- Use an existing Price ID
  You've already got the code for this, just Create your Product on your Stripe account, which will have a child Price ID (it could have more than one, e.g. Product "Python course" might have a "monthly plan" Price object which bills monthly and a "annual plan" Price object).

  ```
  line_items=[
     {'price':price_id, 'quantity':1},
     {'price':price_id_2, 'quantity':2}
  ]
  ```

Note that with Checkout you can have one-time Prices and recurring Prices here. With `mode='subscription'`, you will need to have at least one recurring Price naturally.

- Build an ad-hoc Price in your Checkout Session code
  This is admittedly not as well documented, but an extremely powerful way to handle Prices without having to create them in your Stripe account (or via the API) ahead of time.

  ```
  line_items=[
     # Ad hoc recurring price
     {
        'price_data':{
               'unit_amount':amount,
               'currency':'usd',
               'recurring':{'interval':'month','interval_count':1},
               'product':prod_id
        },
        'quantity':1},
     # Ad hoc one-time price
     {
        'price_data':{
               'unit_amount':amount,
               'currency':'usd',
               'product_dada':{'name':'Product name'}
        },
        'quantity':2},
  ]
  ```

Notice how I use `product` for the first Price and `product_data` for the second (you must use one or the other for any Price). `price_data` allows you to create a Product inline with the Session, the same way `price_data` does it for Prices.

---EDIT---
As per your comments below I don't think this answers your question, your problem is how to pass the customer selection to the backend for multiple Prices without `if` of `case switch` statements.

If I had this requirement, I'd use `lookup_keys`:

- Let's consider two dropdown menus on your front, one for the Product selection and the other for the interval.
- When the customer submits the form, you can concatenate both values to look something like 'prodA-month' or 'prodB-year'.
- On your Stripe account, your Prices are set with lookup_keys just like these.
  https://docs.stripe.com/api/prices/update#update_price-lookup_key
- You can then just pass that concatenated string to the backend, and look for your Price with a Price list and that lookup_key
  https://docs.stripe.com/api/prices/list#list_prices-lookup_keys

You could also just convert the string to the price ID on your backend via other methods such as your own dictionary, but this would be the way to do it using Stripe's infrastructure.

Comment: I am using test mode only, still when I subscribe to the product it doesn't allow me saying I need to activate my account first.
Now, the problem is, I did embed the pricing table to the website directly, but I want to control the look and feel and also want a bit control over the payment flow, like storing subscripton id, previewing invoices based off of it, etc so I chose to add products in the product catalog and call the stripe.Product.list method to show the products in the frontend.

Comment: My problem is, the two products that I have created on stripe dashboard, has two prices each, monthly price and yearly price, so how would I send the priceId to the backend depending upon the user's choice of subscription?
The product array that I get from the stripe.Product.list method, gives me two arrays each array has the data associated with each product, how am I supposed to send this data to the backend. 
I know this is basic, but the simple if else approach looks a bad code practice. so I want to know how it's generally because almost all saas based apps have minimum 3 products.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your problem. Once your customer picks a Product and selects an interval, you can list Prices for this Product and filter the list by `recurring.interval` https://docs.stripe.com/api/prices/list Another thing you can do is not list Products at all, but just list Prices and expand the `product` attribute. Then you'd have a list of all prices and their Product and don't need to fetch any other data. Hopefully this helps

Comment: On second read, I think I get what you mean by "passing to the backend without if statement". I've edited my answer with some suggestion.